# Material UI Autocomplete clear button not cleared selected value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with Autocomplete component. He works well, until I need to clear my selection (i.e. I changed my mind and want to unselect and leave empty field) before submitting form and make state empty. In documentation examples works fine with this task, but in my code it doesn't work.

Here my code:

```
<Autocomplete 
   classes={{
      root: classes.root
   }}
   style={{padding: 0}}
   options={positionArr} 
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
   renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
         {...params}
         className={`inputPadding`}
         classes={{root: classes.labelRoot}}
         label={t('position')}
         variant="outlined"
         helperText={t('optional')}
      />
   )}
   getOptionSelected={(opt, val) => opt === val}
   value={positionObjTwo}
   onChange={(e, val) => {val && setPositionObjTwo(val)}}
/>
```

`positionArr` looks like:

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'AB'
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: 'AB/2OFF'
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you click the clear button icon?

Comment: no, nothing, actually it clear input, but if I click outside input value appear again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `val` is `""` it won't call `setPositionObjTwo(val)` in `onChange={(e, val) => {val && setPositionObjTwo(val)}}`

`""` evaluates to false so the second part of `&&` is not executed. You could fix by changing the line to

`onChange={(e, val) => {(val || val == "") && setPositionObjTwo(val)}}` OR
`onChange={(e, val) => {setPositionObjTwo(val)}}`

Comment: "" shouldn't evaluate to false. When I do this in my browser console, it evaluates to the string. 
```
const str = ""
str && true
""
```

Comment: @technicallynick  Try `"" == false`. (It should return true) Maybe it is different in the browser console.

Comment: My understanding was that evaluations in `&&` was more strict (`===`) than `==`

Comment: I think all truthy evaluations in javascript use `==` unless you explicitly use `===`.